# Как сравнить 2 массива на совпадения с учетом порядка?

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 массива:

**Ответы на вопросы:** `testOne = ['WHY','HOW','HOW','WHOSE','WHAT','WHERE','LONG','DI','IS','WHICHE','WERE'];`

**Ответы на вопросы от пользователя**

```
testOneUser = ['WHY','HOW','HOW','WHOSE','WHAT','WHERE','LONG','DI','IS','WHICHE','WERE'];
```

Как получить точное количество правильных ответов? Сейчас я перебираю массивы но если просто встречается совпадение то оно засчитывается в массив с результатом

```
var testOne = ['WHY','HOW','HOW','WHOSE','WHAT','WHERE','LONG','DI','IS','WHICHE','WERE'];
    $('#test-one-finish').click(function() {
        var testOneUser = $('#test-1 input').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).toArray();
        var testOneChek = [];
        for(var i=0;i<testOne.length;i++){

           for(var j=0;j<testOneUser.length;j++){

             if(testOne[i] == testOneUser[j]){
                 testOneChek.push(testOne[i]);
             }

          }
        }
        $.cookie('test-one-result',testOneChek.length);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var testOneChek = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(testOne.length, testOneUser.length); i++) {
  if (testOne[i] == testOneUser[i]) {
    testOneChek.push(i);
  }
}
```